# HTTP request - error "Missing header 'UUID'"

Tags: http, http-headers, postman, uuid

I've made a HTTP request by using Postman.
Method:POST.
Body (json) :

```
{
"value1" : ["1-JH"], 
"value2": ["Test"],
"value3": true
}
```

But there is an error. Do you know how to fix it?

```
 "message": "Missing header 'UUID'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to guess the exact thing, without knowing more details about your API.

But you can set headers in Postman via the "Headers" tab:

[image]